# Delimit oddly formatted text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, delimiter

I'm trying to find a good way to delimit my text in excel without losing the data.

I have Nastran data, which has data like below:

```
GRID      160125  106000 12.2417-226.961 .557834  106000  
GRID      160126  106000-48.3499-2.75691-2.21477  106000
```

I would like Excel to arrange the data like the following:

```
GRID   |   160125 |  106000 |  12.2417  |  -226.961  |    .557834  |  106000  
GRID   |   160126 |  106000 | -48.3499  |   -2.75691 |  -2.21477   |  106000
```

However, if I delim with space and `-`, it drops the `-` and makes the number positive. Is there a formula I can write so, that if it runs into a `-`, it'll put a space in front and then delim all the data? Or is there a simple way to delim it without a formula?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried fixed length delimiter?

Comment: the problem is that the first like 15 sets of data are like  GRID      106002  106000     0.0-10.2866     0.0  106000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula (assuming your data starts from `A1`): `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," -")`. Autofill it as required, then copy & **special paste** entire column with formulas as **VALUES**. Now you're able to apply text delim with space.

I hope you're happy with the results.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use `Fixed width` delimiting option: at least in your example data columns have a uniform length. Maybe it's otherwise with more data.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Kami's solution and *Fixed width* import worked great.

I saved your input data as a .txt file. Then I opened the text file in Excel. While it placed several breaks at the spaces, I had to click next to the minus signs to create new breaks.

Excel then parsed the columns correctly.

Comment: This is will work only in case each of items in a string has fixed width. For this particular task indeed this is OK.

Comment: Agreed, the OPs numerical data is exactly 8 characters wide.